# Finding chainage of points using Linear Referencing System (LRS)

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, linear-referencing

I have a Shapefile of road that I have converted from a KML file (created on Google Earth) and a txt file containing lat long (from GPS) of points with some attributes. The points are not exactly on the line layer but are very close.

How can I get the chainage of all points from the first point using LRS?

There is an [answer given earlier](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/131516/115) to [Snapping points to line and calculating chainage using Open Source GIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/88433/115) but I have not understood what are the lines route field, points route field and measure field in my layers. I tried to read several notes but to no avail.

Answer (score 4):

As I explained in [Snap points to line and calculate chainage using Open source GIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/88433/snap-points-to-line-and-calculate-chainage-using-open-source-gis/131516#131516) the QGIS [LRS plugin](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/lrs/) accepts points not lying on the line to calibrate it, so it's not a problem that your points are not on the line. By the way, I assume you already loaded the txt file as a point layer (say `gps_layer`).

As you may have already read, you first need to calibrate your route. Such calibration enables you to calculate measures on your route.

I will try to explain once more the parameters you need to calibrate your route based on a couple (start and end) of points. You can create such couple of points digitizing the start and end nodes of the route and saving it to a `calibration` layer which also contains the measures you assign to each point. For instance, start point would have a measure of 0 and your end point would have a measure of 10000 (if your route is 10Km long).

Once you do that, you will use both the route layer and the `calibration` layer, this way:

[image]

- **Lines layer**: The input line layer which contains your route (This would be the layer you obtained after exporting from the KML file).
- **Lines route field**: This is a field on the route layer whose value specifies an ID for the route (say 'route1').
- **Points layer**: The calibration layer with the couple of points (start and end nodes) you created.
- **Points route field**: This is a field in the calibration (point) layer whose value matches the ID of the route (we said 'route1').
- **Measure field**: The field name of the measure you set for your points (remember you set 0 for the start point and 10000 for your end point).
- **Measure unit**: I've used `meters` in the example.

Once your route is calibrated, you can use the `Measures` tab in the plugin GUI and load your `gps_layer`, you find how to use such functionality in my answer to [How to find Chainage of points using QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/129495/how-to-find-chainage-of-points-using-qgis?lq=1) (Numeral 2.)

I hope it's clear now. If it's not, try to ask something more specific (after a first try from your side).